# Installing MAC OS useing virtualbox On Windows 8.1

Tags: macos, operating-system, window, installation, virtualbox

I am trying to install Mac(OSX-Mavericks) using virtualbox On Windows 8.1.

Everything works fine But, when MAC Installation setup starts in virtual machine, it keep on loading and do not start the installation wizard stays on the first screen.
I have waited for a log time like 3-4 hrs but unable to figure out the problem as there is no error.
I am using a dell(Inspiron 3537).

I have installed Mac on my previous Samsung laptop successfully in the same way.
I will provide other information on demand as I'm not sure where the problem is as setup loads but not starts the installation process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't provided any useful information to deserve any help. Please add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

enable virtualisation on your BIOS, it may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open an administrator CMD shell and try this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox"
VBoxManage modifyvm <name_of_your_vm> --cpuidset 00000001 000306a9 00020800 80000201 178bfbff
```

Then close/VirtualBox and open again (to save your new settings). Boot OSX with "-v" flag.